# SF2 IvoryGoogleMapBundle - How to display the map in my .twig?

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, twig

When i try to display my Map in my twig file, this error appear and 
i don't understand why :

> Unknown "google_map" function in TestFrontBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 11.

My controller

```
<?php

namespace Test\ZeroBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Map;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Overlays\Animation;
use Ivory\GoogleMap\Overlays\Marker;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $map = new Map();

        $map->setCenter(-34.919,-57.954, true);
        $map->setMapOption('zoom', 13);
        $map->setLanguage('fr');

        $marker = new Marker();

        // Configure your marker options
        $marker->setPrefixJavascriptVariable('marker_');
        $marker->setPosition(-34.919,-57.954, true);
        $marker->setAnimation(Animation::BOUNCE);

        $marker->setOption('clickable', false);
        $marker->setOption('flat', true);
        $marker->setOptions(array(
            'clickable' => false,
            'flat'      => true,
        ));

        $map->addMarker($marker);





        return $this->render('TestZeroBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'map' => $map
        ));
    }
}
```

My twig file

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{%  block title %} ProjectZero {%  endblock %}


{%  block body %}
    {% include "TestFrontBundle:Includes:indexBody.html.twig" %}


        {{ google_map(map) }}



    {%  endblock %}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

With the symfony bundle you need to use the `ivory_google_map` function

```
{%  block body %}
    {% include "TestFrontBundle:Includes:indexBody.html.twig" %}
    {{ ivory_google_map(map) }}
    {{ ivory_google_api([map]) }}
{%  endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
{%  block body %}

  {% include "TestFrontBundle:Includes:indexBody.html.twig" %}

  {{ google_map_container(map) }}
  {{ google_map_css(map) }}
  {{ google_map_js(map) }}

{%  endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes... Unknown "google_map_container" function in TestFrontBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 11.

Comment: Did you load the Api in `base.html.twig`: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>` ?